The arrow inside string
In Mathematica, if using ->, it gets automatically replaced with a nicely looking arrow. However, if using "->", the replacement does not occur. How to fix this?

Try "\[RightArrow]"

Look at the reference page for \[RightArrow] to see how you can enter it.
Either type in \[RightArrow], or use the alias escspace->esc.

(+1) To be pedantic, the FullForm of "esc->esc" is "\[Rule]"  but the FullForm of "esc ->esc" (with a space after the first esc) is "\[RightArrow]" (here)
